# Confidentiality and Integrity violation in database security

Tags: databases, integrity, confidentiality

I read some topics on database security. Now I have two questions about confidentiality and integrity violation, Thanks anyone who answers me:

1. If we consider knowing the availability of data as a type of
   confidentiality disclosure, what is the referential integrity
   problem in database security?
2. Can confidentiality violation lead to integrity violation?

Comment: Could you link what you have read please?

Comment: Not a specific page that I link you to read, and these questions in my mind:) @Aria

Comment: This smells a lot like homework to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) If we consider knowing the availability of data is a type of
>   confidentiality disclosure?

Yes, knowing the availability of data is a type of confidentiality violation. Example is error message revealing whether a username exists  or not in the database.

> 2) What is the referential integrity problem in database security?

For database elements to be consistently synchronized, multiple tables which segregates data about a single attribute has to be linked properly. In otherwords, no rogue data set should exist.

Suppose I have an application with two database tables `user_credentials` & `user_activity`.

`user_credentials` has columns `user_name` and `user_passwd`.
`user_activity` has `user_name` & `user_lastlogintime`.

Referential integrity is the property by which both the tables have exactly all the same values in `user_name` field. This ensures consistency in accessing or removing the table elements.

> 3) Can confidentiality violation lead to integrity violation?

It is possible. But both has to be considered separately. Consider a scenario where a broken hashing algorithm with a known collission is used. Knowledge about the broken algorithm can be used to bypass the integrity checks. But from an Information security perspective theintegrity violation happens because of the use of a broken algorithm, though it is a result of confidentiality compromise.

Comment: I have two questions, but you answer three questions! I know what is referential integrity, my mean in question 1 is "referential integrity problem in database security when we know availability of some data" but you just explain "what is referential integrity".

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I still am unable to comprehend it.

Comment: i.e. Can referential integrity discloses availability of data in database and lead to confidential violation?

Comment: Yes. A referential integrity flaw can lead to information disclosure which is a confidentiality violation

Comment: But how? Can you clarify an example?

Answer (score 0):

"Can referential integrity discloses availability of data in database and lead to confidential violation"

It is possible. In a simple example, an attempt to delete a customer record may fail if there is an order or payment record belonging to the customer. However  this only works if there are circumstances where deletion is allowed. Often data items are never 'hard-deleted' (removed) but are simply marked as 'deleted','archived' or 'inactive'.

In the other direction, the insertion of a payment record may be rejected if the customer doesn't exist. But if the identifiers are arbitrary, then the attacker often worn't be able to try this without already knowing the customer identifier. More likely they'll be able to make estimates of the numbers of employees, customers, invoices etc... in the system.

Uniqueness constraints are more likely to lead to information leakage (eg credit card, phone number or email address is already in the system).

Comment: Tnx for your answer!